# Catch multiple Task callbacks via Continuewith

Tags: c#, .net, task

I wanna run multiple tasks in the same time. Every task will return a value type.

Can anyone tell me how to catch all of the callbacks via `ContinueWith`?

My test code:

```
        static async Task<List<string>> ListAsync()
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            return new List<string>() { "Item 1", "Item 2" };
        }

        static async Task<int> IntAsync()
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            return 10;
        }

        static async Task<string> StringAsync()
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            return "My string";
        }

        static async Task Test()
        {
            Task t1 = StringAsync();
            Task t2 = IntAsync();
            Task t3 = ListAsync();
            await Task.WhenAny(t1, t2, t3).ContinueWith(t =>
            {
                //how can I catch callbacks here?
            });
        }
```

Comment: I am not sure what exactly are you trying to do. Do you wan't to call the continuation for all 3 tasks?

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic Yes. I'm waiting for the responses of 3 tasks to continue.

Comment: *Why* aren't you using `Task.WhenAll`? And why are you mixing `ContinueWith` with `await`?

Comment: If your methods already return `Task<T>` objects, why are you using only `Task`, you can use `Task<T>.Result`

Comment: @Luizgrs that would be a very bad idea - `.Result` blocks. Besides, there's absolutely no reason for this as `await` *does* return the result, *after* the tasks complete

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos If I remove `await` there, it will throw warning: `Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed. Consider applying the 'await' operator to the result of the call.`

Comment: You misunderstood. Why are you using `ContinueWith` *at all*? Just do `await Task.WhenAny(t1, t2, t3);` and you're done.

Comment: @HappyCoding The problem is `ContinueWith`, not `await`. Just call `var results=await Task.WhenAll(t1,t2,t3);` and check the results of the tasks

Comment: in fact the question is confusing, I understood that you was looking for the results when you say "how to catch all of the callbacks"

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Error syntax: `Cannot assign void to an implicitly-type variable`

Comment: @Luaan And... how can I detect the reponses of 3 tasks?

Comment: Depends on what you want to do with them. If you simply want to treach each of them in some way, you don't need `Task.WhenAll` in the first place - just do `var result1 = await t1; var result2 = await t2; var result3 = await t3;`. If you do use `WhenAll`, you can simply read the result with `t1.Result` etc. afterwards. And of course, `Task.WhenAll` returns you all the tasks, so if you need to do the same thing to all the tasks, just build a `foreach` over the result of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to retrieve the results of all tasks, once they are all finished, you can simply use `Task.WhenAll`. If all tasks return the same result, the [Task.WhenAll(Task[]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194874(v=vs.110).aspx) overload will return a Task. In this case,  `await Task.WhenAll` will return an array with the tasks' result in order:

```
var t1=Task.Run(()=>{...;return 1});
var t2=Task.Run(()=>{...;return 2});
var t3=Task.Run(()=>{...;return 3});

int[] results=await Task.WhenAll(t1,t2,t3);
//Check t1's result
Debug.Assert(results[0]==1);
```

When the tasks return different results, the [Task.WhenAll(params Task[])](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160374(v=vs.110).aspx) is called which returns only a Task. You can still access the results of each task though, using its `Result` property withouth any risk of blocking:

```
var t1=Task.Run(()=>{...;return 1});
var t2=Task.Run(()=>{...;return "Hi"});
var t3=Task.Run(()=>{...;return new[]{1,2,3}});

await Task.WhenAll();

Debug.Assert(t2.Result=="Hi");
```

There's no reason to use `ContinueWith` when using `await`, as awaiting does *roughly* the same thing as using `ContinueWith` - It doesn't start any asynchronous executions, it *awaits without blocking* for already running tasks to complete, it extracts the results and sets the synchronization context to what it was before awaiting started.

Comment: ya, I prefer this way rather than using `foreach`.

Comment: Can I have a small question? I notice that you say about `ContinueWith`: ` it extracts the results and sets the synchronization context to what it was before awaiting started`. Why don't `the results` contain something like `t1.Result` or `t2.Result` or `t3.Result` as your demo?

Answer (score 1):

If you wan't to call the tasks with different continuations, you need to specify continuation for each task:

```
static async Task Test()
{
    Task t1 = StringAsync().ContinueWith(t => System.Console.Out.WriteLine("string"));
    Task t2 = IntAsync().ContinueWith(t => System.Console.Out.WriteLine("int"));
    Task t3 = ListAsync().ContinueWith(t => System.Console.Out.WriteLine("list"));
    await Task.WhenAny(t1, t2, t3); 
    // use WhenAll if you want to wait until all tasks are done
}
```

`WhenAny` will complete when any of the child tasks is done, and then trigger the continuation, so the continuation would be called only once.

If you want to call the callback once after all the tasks are finished, the simplest way is this:

```
static async Task Test()
{
    Task t1 = StringAsync();
    Task t2 = IntAsync();
    Task t3 = ListAsync();
    await Task.WhenAll(t1, t2, t3); 
    // your continuation logic here
}
```

Comment: No reason for such code - `WhenAny` will return the results of the Tasks in order

Comment: Seems strange to mix `ContinueWith` with `async/await`. For me it's generally a one-or-the-other decision, with a strong bias to the latter.

Comment: I believe that the OP thinks that WhenAny somehow loops through all tasks, but I didn't want to drift too far away from the original question,

Comment: Sorry, but is there another way to combine 3 `ContinueWith` to 1 line instead of 3 lines in your example?

Comment: That's why I put `await` before `ContinueWith`

Comment: If you have 3 different continuations, you need to specify each of them. I believe that you are trying to explain the solution, while problem could be something else. Could you describe it?

Comment: It seems that you are confused about how `await` functions.

Comment: Something maybe: `wait until all tasks are done and use the returned value to continue`

Comment: @HappyCoding No, no, no - `await` is an operator. Its argument *includes* the `ContinueWith` - that's how expressions work in C#. Would you expect that `+myObject.Left` will apply the `+` operator to `myObject`? Of course not. `await` works the same way. Whatever happens after the `await` *is* (logically) a continuation of the task. So the `await` isn't *before* the `ContinueWith` - it "happens" afterwards.

Comment: but what is the returned value? return value of which of those 3 tasks?

Comment: @Luaan ya. I've read your comment above. You understand mine exactly. But I wanna use `await` for all tasks instead of using `await` for per task with `foreach`. Is it possible?

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic If you declare `var t1 = await ListAsync();`, you will get the value: `new List<string>(){ "Item 1", "Item 2"}`

Comment: I know, but I understood that you want to execute tasks concurrently, and not wait sequentially for all of them.

Comment: @HappyCoding Oh, I think I see where you're getting confused - `await` doesn't do anything with the tasks, it *only* awaits their result. When all the tasks are completed, it will synchronously retrieve their results (and throw exceptions, if any). But the tasks are only started once, at the point you call e.g. `ListAsync()`, and they will execute in parallel. It's important to call all the methods first, and *then* await the tasks they return. That's why I used `await t1;` instead of `await ListAsync();` - they do something different.

Comment: That's why you can't have one continuation function: one would receive list, one number and one string.